# SQL- How to query the whole table and grouped values

Tags: sql, ms-access

If I have Two Tables, Students and Grades for example, and there is a relationship between them, Students.ID = Grades.studentID, how do I query the average of the Grades in the Grade table and compare it to the individual student grade average.

I've been stuck on this for quite a while, this is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Students.studentName 
FROM Students, Grades 
WHERE AVG(grade) < (SELECT AVG(grade) GROUP BY studentName);

   ^This part is to                 ^This part is to     
    find out the                     find out individual
    overall grade                    grade average
    average
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to do this in one single SELECT statement in MS Access, but it is easy if you create a saved query that just provides the overall grade average from the grade table data.  You might name that query something like **qGradeAverage** and it would look something like this:

`SELECT AVG([grade]) AS OverallGradeAverage FROM Grades;`

Then add this to your final query.

```
SELECT Students.StudentID, Students.StudentName, Avg(Grades.Grade) AS StudentGradeAverage, qGradeAverage.OverallGradeAverage
FROM qGradeAverage, Grades INNER JOIN Students ON Grades.StudentID = Students.StudentID
GROUP BY Students.StudentID, Students.StudentName, qGradeAverage.OverallGradeAverage;
```

Note: If you are using SQL Server, you could do this in a single stored procedure by getting the average first and saving it as a variable.